# Mapbox unresolved dependencies android SDK

Tags: android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to make an android app with Mapbox SDK in android studio, and just to get familiar I am running through [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/) tutorial.

However I am getting dependency errors. Other posts have suggested flicking back to 9.5.0 but that has the same issues.

Project build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                username = 'mapbox'
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where my private access token is in a text file called gradle.properties as MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN.

The error I get is:

```
Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-telemetry/6.2.2/mapbox-android-telemetry-6.2.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

try to add it in settings.gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        credentials {
            // Do not change the username below.
            // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
            username = 'mapbox'
            // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
            password = ['Token'] ?: ""

        }
    }
}
```

}